# How do I replace all special characters in a string with the escape character?

Tags: c++

If I had a string that looked like `\"A\\nB\"`, how do I transform it to look like `"A\nB"`?

The `\n` portion should work as a new line. It should not be printing "A\nB", it should be printing as follows:

```
A
B
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate function for removing **escape** characters from your `std::string` in a following way:

```cpp
std::string remove_escape_char(std::string const& s) {
    std::string result;
    auto it = s.begin();
    while (it != s.end()) {
        char c = *it++;
        if (c == '\\' && it != s.end()) {
            switch (*it++) {
            case '\\':
                c = '\\';
                break;
            case 'n':
                c = '\n';
                break;
            default: 
                continue;
            }
        }
        result += c;
    }

    return result;
}
```

and then the function for removing **special** characters from `std::string`:

```cpp
void remove_special_char(std::string& str, char c) {
    auto position = str.find(c);
    while (position != std::string::npos) {
        str.erase(position, 1);
        position = str.find(c);
    }
}
```

You can use above two functions like:

```cpp
std::string str{"\"A\\nB\""};
remove_special_char(str, 0x22); // remove "
std::cout << remove_escape_char(str) << std::endl;
```

Now the output should be:

```
A
B
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEAFZOpLegAyeWpgByxgEaZiIAMwAOUgAdUBUJ1Wj1DE0EAoLU6OwdnIzcPTwA2RWVMVRCGAmZiAjDjUwt0lRjaHLyCOKdXdy9fBVz8wojLJqqahKSvFIBKRVQDYmQOAHIpT3tkQywAanFPHXUm4kxmI0XscQAGAEFJ6dnMBaXV%2B2At3YP9pvQQEHPRObWjVAA3TAB9TAUWP2%2ByAQeQgdweT2AczQtCaUhScwUfQWAHZZPs5hiEQR7o8CMQLi9fgZWARFmi9pi5swDEQ5oRTgARBEAOjcwHsED6ZOulIA7gg8Ow5hB6WAwIsmQpmdZOUjxKieZTMUC8lDGXMAFSEOQ6zzkpWYvBUYXIRkSuZgCZmHTia2WhaSFJwukEC3izyS6XaWUo/UGpUKXmEIHCrWkmRyOUK9H%2ByksJQWq02u1jECK2MG03my225M6HN69MZykuNbMADW3JjxfjJ0ttEtaerxeV6pz1obE0LzZbc1L60r3YpLawVGpJJACx7LehaloBkwVeHxflDKLlNX68xawUxNduqZEiHG%2BRa/2RbWBGGtEJu5JS835/271QeHQhLeny%2BCgByDwbC%2BFViFBbFwTxC5nVWUgoWBYgoSjP0MWpWkomCOh1VWZkqHsdAIGQLlj0xflBROCBUPKN1zTBXF8VEB5aCiBCtwxTD3GYJQyMCNDaGgzgCMQpVyJCDC8SwnC8P4otHwOU9rmuexXSMZgOSY25QJoglVnlWRJEkXMpEkA5rVzWhZGM3SDM3IdXg%2Bb4f0yf9WEA2CQLIOYdgAD10/i5gAel8j9bIdPS1JxNAaVOG0lkCr9fn%2BQEXNWOUlkWHQsRxaxWCXSlL2vdyH1PMYBlYEAxjMMZSFMMYdgq1BSptCMZARIYRhOSZOAqghSpqvoBnLcxJGZFJPGRHZkTMZFOG8HZODMFJ5qEUruAqqqatIOqxgqhQQB2UguuqorSDgWAYEQFBUCMPwSLICg8Iuq72A8YAFFoZg/AUBBUAIUhsJJdxtogFxuoqlx7DyABPUqOtINAjCMLQCAAeVoVhIYO0gsCU0R2GBjG8DWLJPm29HMA8zIaXGNaFOUXHWDwUsIb0LAoc6/EjBZgYaHoJg2A4Hh%2BEEYQ6IkRr5DplxtsgAZUD8cpiYAWnlu4JRFnTpE4aGlDKEJNG0VpTEsawujqDxLCEuh9ciLjymNxJ6naDIsjoSoWn0IpBC1zJyhd6p7FqO3TcUZoCjdtog86P3untgYFBa0YuGK0rysq3GNo87wUnllJuDmYBkFNCA8QMWhyyRCBcEIEgHU8Sw5j0S7rurvi651GROuB3rSH6kbmTMRaxmW0h2bMXbVtq0qtp2vaO6O06ICQIYCD8GlyEoWGHvtqx8CIQOucYFgcf53liDejn%2B%2BTsf1tK9q5iDAgEDmdPM%2Bz3P8%2BFIuS76duDs7hB1iwDwnJ%2B6D2HqPVOE9FBT32j1PqIBuDImZKkSQABOSQ3BJDeE4Mg7w3BPCeF4CVMYngVrgM2tPH%2BicxiSBIejDa38YGkE%2BMQIIGhuBAA%3D)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work:

```cpp
if(example.size() > 1) {
    for (auto i = 0ul; i < example.size() - 1; ++i) // loop through the string char by char
        if (example[i] != '\\' || (example[i + 1] == '\\'))
            result += example[i]; // if the current one is a \ and the next char is different to \ (for the case of \\) remove it
    if (example[example.size() - 1] == '\\' && example[example.size() - 1] == '\\') result += '\\'; // check for the last char
} else if(example.size() == 1 && example[0] != '\\') result+=example[0]; // check for special case there the string is just one char long
```

Comment: @Memento yes, not for you? can you please post the code you are using to test it?

Comment: Note that the loop here runs out of bounds if `s` is empty.

Comment: @PeteBecker yes sorry

Comment: The if clause in this statement is never triggered. I'm running it verbatim.

Comment: @Memento no, literally copy and paste this code and add a cout inside the for and you will see that it will prints. I don't want the device but the code you are using to test this

Comment: @Berto99 I'll repeat again, I'm running your code verbatim.  It seems the 'if' clause is never triggered because the program sees the escape character and its subsequent character as one single character.

Comment: Did you mean `"\\\"A\\\\nB\\\""` instead of `"\"A\\nB\""` ?

Comment: @Memento i've changed the code, can you please try with this (note that now the output is inside the `result` variable)